# webpack exception when using express middleware router

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, react-hot-loader

I have a simple webpack with react hotloader & express setup and working.  I'm trying to add an external node module that will register a sub router for some services.  For some reason, doing so causes a strange exception (see below).

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

var app = express();

var router = express.Router();

var mod = require("my-module");
mod.registerServices(router); // <-- adds routes to the router
app.use("/api/v1*", router); // <-- This line causes the error

var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));


app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

The Exception:

```
$ node server.js 
/Users/bmonro/Documents/Code/nui-redux/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js:51
    throw new Error('locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module ' + 'replacement API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in ' + 'production by using `env` section in Babel configuration. See the ' + 'example in README: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr');
    ^

Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replacement API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration. See the example in README: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr
    at Object.proxyReactComponents [as default] (/Users/bmonro/Documents/Code/nui-redux/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js:51:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bmonro/Documents/Code/nui-redux/src/ext/nui-company-admin/lib/CompanyLocation/components/simple.js:25:60)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bmonro/Documents/Code/nui-redux/src/ext/nui-company-admin/lib/CompanyLocation/containers/CompanyLocationPage.js:13:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
```

**UPDATE**
Turns out that removing this from `.babelrc`  where I have some react transforms enabled and subsequently removing all of the web pack hotloader plugins & middleware gets the router working again.

```
                {
                    "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                    "imports": ["react"],
                    "locals": ["module"]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: don't use babel-plugin-react-transform in .babelrc, use config in webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        query: {
          plugins: [
            ["react-transform", {
              transforms: [{
                transform: "react-transform-hmr",
                imports: ["react"],
                locals: ["module"]
              }]
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Details:

- https://github.com/gaearon/babel-plugin-react-transform/issues/62
- https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr/issues/5